# Regarding ideal of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let  $\mathcal{I}$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{N}$  i.e.,  if $A\in \mathcal{I}$  and $B\subset A$ then $B \in \mathcal{I}$  and  if  $A, B \in \mathcal{I}$  then  $A\cup B  \in \mathcal{I}.$  Then  if $\mathcal{I}$ has  the  property  that  for  any  $A\subset \mathbb{N}$   and  $B\subset\mathbb{N}$   either  $A\setminus  B \in \mathcal{I}$  or  $B\setminus A  \in \mathcal{I}$  then  can  anyone please  suggest  me  that  what type of  ideal is this.

Comment: It is an ideal such that  for  any  $A\subset \mathbb{N}$   and  $B\subset\mathbb{N}$   either  $A\setminus  B \in \mathcal{I}$  or  $B\setminus A  \in \mathcal{I}$. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Obvious examples that come to mind are of course $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, and the set of subsets not containing a fixed element $a\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: A property of those ideals is that $P(\mathbb{N})/\mathcal{I}$ is a singleton. This is because for all $A,B\subset\mathbb{N}$, wither $A\setminus B\in\mathcal{I}$ or $B\setminus A\in\mathcal{I}$. But the symmetric difference $A\Delta B$ is a superset of both $A\setminus B$ and $B\setminus A$. Therefore $A\Delta B\in\mathcal{I}$ for all pairs of subsets $A,B\subset \mathcal{N}$.